# wtpwebapps/myapp is empty when running Tomcat under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, publish

I know that tomcat is running because when I type http://localhost, the tomcat page dispay. My problem is I can't figure out why the wtpwebapps/myapp is empty, is like the eclipse doesn't publish it and when i type http://localhost/myapp, I get 404 error.

In the server overview :

- Server Location is set to "Use Tomcat installation" | server path: the servers's folder  | deploy path : wtpwebapps
- Server Option : Publish module contexts to separate XML file
- Publishing : Automatically publish when ressource change

I use eclipse Ganymede 3.4.2, tomcat 6.0, under Win7

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your files must be somwhere, so start searching in:

```
<YOUR_WORKSPACE_DIR>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp<SOME_NUMBER>\wtpwebapps
```

Comment: @Moh, wtpwebapps is on the end of my path. So you have the problem with localize your /wtpwebapps - I've given you one proposition

Comment: Well actually I changed the deploiment folder to /wtpwebapps
The problem is when I run Tomcat, all the files in the app folder /wtpwebapps/myapp are deleted and only the WEB-INF left ...when I copy the files manualy it works but then again when I publish...it delete All...any tips ?

Comment: I looked at the path you gave me, after tmp0 there is no sub folders

Comment: I guess that you have something broken with your webapp project in Eclipse and this cause that when you publish project it removes all. Try to add new web project (by eclipse new project wizard) and check if you will have similar problem

Comment: You are right smas, the project I was working on was imported and it doesn't follow the structure of eclipse web project.
So I created a new project, copy the .java to src folder that I create, copy the .jsp, web-inf and meta-inf  to the webContent.
I think before the problem is Eclipse doesn't see the webContent so it doesn't replace the removed files
Thanks smas

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, when updating our project (`.project` and `.classpath` are checked in for convenience, but causes sometimes problems).

Console-Log in eclipse always says:

`Error configuring application listener of class org.sth.ThisClass
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sth.ThisClass`

The **reason** was that `$WORKSPACE_DIR/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp$NUMBER/wtpwebapps/$CONTEXT/WEB-INF/lib/classes` was empty. The **solution** was to enter under `Project Properties > Deployment Assembly` an entry:

Source: `/src`

Deploy Path: `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: This fixed my issue with getting HTTP 404 Errors .  This was not an obvious problem.  Thumbs up!

Comment: with this workaround the classes appeared under wtpwebapps, but the error remains

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Maven in your project, this is a solution for you:

1. Delete the project(s) in the Eclipse.
2. create project from Maven sources (select your workspace directory).
3. Check found pom.xml to import.

Restart the Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into servers explorer and it will show you what state is your application at and if its deployed.

Comment: When you open server confing by double clicking your server from server explorer you will see the location and you can even change it: Sever Locations -> Sever path

Answer (score 0):

Since I had difficulty finding where this "server overview" is, I like to add that you just double click on a server under the "servers" view.  I kept on right click and look at the "Properties" and was not getting to this information.